# Per product flat rate shipping WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I'd like to do per product shipping programmatically. And I don't want to use the plugin. This seems like it would easy:

1. add meta field called "shipping_price" for each product.
2. hook into checkout and update shipping based off each products "shipping_price" that's in your cart

I know how to do #1. but any ideas on the best way to achieve #2?

Comment: I have answered your question. To give an appropriate answer without offering multiple options in my answer it would be interesting if you could update your question with the code from step 1. Maybe not so much for yourself but for other users who want to use this question and answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in the following way, using `get_post_meta` to get the meta field `'shipping_price'`

Note 1: to test this code added a line with dummy data

Note 2: Don't forget to specify the `$rate->method_id`

```php
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // Set variable
    $cost = 0; 

    // Loop through line items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $line_item ) {
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $line_item['product_id'];

        // Quantity
        $quantity = $line_item['quantity'];

        // Get post meta
        $shipping_price = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'shipping_price', true);

        // DEBUG, for testing purposes, REMOVE AFTERWARDS!!
        $shipping_price = 10;

        if ( $shipping_price ) {
            $cost += $shipping_price * $quantity;
        }
    }

    if ( $cost > 0 ) {
        // (Multiple)
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {

            // Targeting
            if ( in_array( $rate->method_id, array( 'free_shipping', 'distance_rate', 'table_rate' ) ) ) {
                // Set rate cost
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $cost;
            }
        }   

        // Single
        // Set rate cost
        // $rates['free_shipping']->cost = $cost;
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks alot! this is really close. 
your single rate cost was...
$rates['free_shipping']->cost = $cost;
needs to be...
$rates['flat_rate:1']->set_cost($cost);

Comment: Indeed, my answer takes several options into account because your question was rather 'broad'. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on 7uc1f3rs answer. I had to slightly modify to get it to work with WooCommerce 3.0+ new way of doing it.

```
$rates[$rate_key]->cost = $cost;
```

needs to be

```
$rates[$rate_key]->set_cost($cost);
```

You can use functions from https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Rate.html for $rates

```
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

// Set variable
$cost = 0; 

// Loop through line items
foreach( $package['contents'] as $line_item ) {
    // Get product id
    $product_id = $line_item['product_id'];

    // Quantity
    $quantity = $line_item['quantity'];

    // Get post meta
    //$shipping_price = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'shipping_price', true);

    // DEBUG, for testing purposes, REMOVE AFTERWARDS!!
    $shipping_price = 10;

    if ( $shipping_price ) {
        $cost += $shipping_price * $quantity;
    }
}

if ( $cost > 0 ) {
    // (Multiple)
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {

        // Targeting
        if ( in_array( $rate->method_id, array( 'free_shipping', 'flat_rate' ) ) ) {
            // Set rate cost
            // use functions from https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Rate.html
            $rates[$rate_key]->set_cost($cost);
        }
    }

    // Single
    // Set rate cost
    //$rates['flat_rate:1']->set_cost($cost);

    // use this to see your rates
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($rates); echo '</pre>';
}

return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 100, 2 );
```